# How to use loop with a Screen Flow

Tags: lightning-experience, screen-flow

How to solve this?
A screen flow that asks for an email address, finds all contacts with that email address, and checks the “Email Opt Out” box on each contact

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
This is my solution, idk whats wrong!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [Edit] your question to add more details. If you're new to Salesforce (or a part/feature thereof) then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better resource to get you started.

Comment: Please check again! I have added screenshots

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all the fancy steps here. Just query the contacts and update them with the Update Records feature. It should look like this.

[image: Email Opt Out Flow]

[image: Opt Out Contacts element]

As to why your original flow isn't working? Hard to tell. Everything looks fine, so we'd have to debug it to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: Could you explain the step? email equals email to opt out value? did you create a variable?

Comment: In my original I was trying to loop through, what would be the solution if done through loop?

Comment: the solution is not working! What did you create in screen element?

Comment: @rameesha It's literally just an email input field. Nothing special. Have you tried running the flow in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here's how you can do it. I have used an update element where you can directly specify the condition to filter out the contacts with the email address you entered. However, I had to create a custom field for email opt-out as it was not directly writable in the flows.